# ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470 Graphics (switchable)

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I know there are a few threads with this very same issue. But none have actually generated a solution. So the laptop is an [HP Pavilion dv6-3150sa](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02531007-1&jumpid=ba_r329_hhoaffiliate&aid=38293&pbid=je6NUbpObpQ&aoid=35252&siteid=je6NUbpObpQ-aXzoKdQOQFh3LkijtLVZhA) which has an integrated Intel GPU and a dedicated ATI GPU. I am permanently stuck using the Intel GPU and wish to switch to the ATI GPU.

NOT working solutions:

- Install fglrx (puts laptop into low-graphics recovery)
- Use VGA switcheroo (this does not exist on this laptop)
- Install AMD Catalyst Control Centre
- Use BIOS to switch cards (there is no option in BIOS)

I have listed these so people DO NOT suggest them. They do not work trust me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage it?

Comment: Did you tried to blacklist intel gpu kernel module